# When should one fully implement an inserter/extractor?

Tags: c++

Let's say I am defining an inserter for a class:

```
struct X
{
    string name;
    int age;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X& x)
{
    return os << x.name << x.year;
}
```

I guess since there is already an inserter defined for strings and integers I should use it inside the function. But when is it appropriate to implement my own inserter and use facets and iterators instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have formatting requirements which go beyond the default formatting for whatever type you're outputting.  For example, suppose you want to format the `X::name` field in uppercase.  You'd need to implement a custom routine to insert only uppercase characters into the `ostream`.

Example:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X& x)
{
    std::transform(x.name.begin(), x.name.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(os),
        ::toupper);
    os << ", " << x.age;
    return os;
}
```